# How can I install the redhat-release package on AWS

Tags: oracle, amazon-ec2, redhat

Oracle has a dependency on re

While trying to

```
sudo yum -y  localinstall oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I get

```
Error: Package: oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64 (/oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64)
       Requires: /etc/redhat-release
```

My AMI is

```
Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-00eb20669e0990cb4
```

Comment: try to build manually instead of using a .rpm

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: download the rpms and install locally

sudo yum -y localinstall compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum -y localinstall compat-libcap1-1.10-7.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: @user939857 Have you able to fix it ? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score -2):

export CV_ASSUME_DISTID=OEL7.6